# How to combine 2 discrete colormaps in matpotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap, stacked-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I want to create a stacked bar chart with more than 20 discrete classes. The largest discrete colormap only has 20 colors, which is note enough for me. Below are the discrete colormaps:

[image]

My idea is to combine/concatenate colormaps tab20b and tab20c such that I have 40 discrete colors. Is this easily doable in python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your custom colormap:

```
from matplotlib import cm, colors

cmap = colors.ListedColormap(cm.tab20.colors + cm.tab20c.colors, name='tab40')
```

[image]